# oracle sql query to get column values without space

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to run a query to select values from a column in a table, which doesn't have space at specific position in the data in the column. i.e. first two positions.

```
Select test_col from A where SUBSTR(test_col, 0 ,2) <> ' '
```

So far, it's returning columns with have space in the beginning two position.

Any Suggestion.

Example:

```
test_col
  Quick Brown Fox
Black Sheep
  This a test
Mary had a little lamb
```

So the query should return **Black Sheep** and **Mary had a little lamb**.

Comment: You need to elaborate. Could you show some sample data and what the output would look like?

Comment: Ok update with example.

Comment: Setting up a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is always helpful too.

Comment: Is `test_col` a `VARCHAR` or a `CHAR` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 10g and later:

```
SELECT test_col FROM a WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(test_col, '^[^ ]{2}.*$');
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46018/11)**

Comment: Thanks it gives error of invalid relational operator ora-00920

Comment: Sorry about that. Should've tested.  Give me a few and I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks it works now. There are more than one correct answer. Since you provided sql fiddle. So i am accepting your answer. Thanks to every one for their help and time.

Answer (score 4):

Your index should start with 1 and not 0 and I prefer Trim and check for null over checking for space in data. Try this

```
Select test_col from A where Trim(SUBSTR(test_col, 1 ,2)) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select test_col 
  from A 
 where SUBSTR(test_col, 1, 1) <> ' '
   and SUBSTR(test_col, 2, 1) <> ' ';
```

OR (even better)

```
select test_col 
  from A 
 where INSTR(SUBSTR(test_col, 1, 2), ' ') = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first positional index of a string is 1, not 0 (though [SUBSTR() treats it as 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114)) and you're only testing for *one* space:

```
select test_col from A where SUBSTR(test_col, 1, 2) <> '  '
```

Comment: I tried before with indices (1,2) it returns the data which has space in those two positions.

Comment: You're checking for _one_ space though @Nomad, not _two_.

Comment: you are right, thanks. But same result if i change indices to 1,3 instead of 1,2 etc.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your answer and help.

Comment: Of course @Nomad, if you're testing for 3 spaces you have to check whether it's not equal to 3 spaces!

Comment: The idea is to get records which don't have spaces in first two positions/places.

Comment: I think I understand the problem @Nomad, the third variable in SUBSTR() is not the second positional index but the _length_ you want to take from the first index.